# How to show all pagination pages, not just next two pages

Tags: pagination

I'm using the native EE pagination and it's only showing the next two pages (i.e. 1, 2 & 3) when there's actually 4 pages. Once you go to page two it then shows all numbers (1,2,3 & 4) but I'd like it to show all pages all the time.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Here's my code:

```
{paginate}
    <div class="top-strip subtle pagination actual_pagination">
        {pagination_links}
            <h3><span class="page-label">Page:</span>
                {page}
                    <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}current{/if} pagination-button">{pagination_page_number}</a>
                {/page}
            </h3>
            <h3 class="right">
                {first_page}
                    <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first pagination-button">First</a>
                {/first_page}
                {previous_page}
                    <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous pagination-button">Previous</a>
                {/previous_page}
                {next_page}
                    <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next pagination-button">Next</a>
                {/next_page}
                {last_page}
                    <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last pagination-button">Last</a>
                {/last_page}
            </h3>
        {/pagination_links}
    </div><!-- /end #top-strip -->
{/paginate}
```

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to mosey on over to `page_padding` land.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/templates/pagination.html#id3

```
{pagination_links page_padding="10"}

{/pagination_links}
```

This will show up to 10 page numbers on either side of the current page in the pagination links.

Comment: Thanks @jrothafer, do you know which version page_padding was introduced with?

Comment: Nope, the term doesn't even show up in the change log for EE2, so I'm guessing sometime during EE1.